# Add another cookie when session is created

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, struts2

In my web application developed in struts 2 (javax.servlet v 2.5 and an embedded tomcat lib), I have the JSESSIONID always automatically added to the cookies after the first request when a HttpSession is created (at first call to request.getSession()), I know that the JSESSIONID aims to identify the created http session.

Now I want to add more cookies but I don't found how to adding this cookie in the framework struts 2?  and how can I remove it from the cookie of the response when user logged out.

Answer (score 2):

Add cookieName Cookie:

```
Cookie newCookie = new Cookie("cookieName", "cookieValue");
newCookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24*365); //Store cookie for 1 year
response.addCookie(newCookie);
```

and then remove it:

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

if (cookies != null) {
 for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
   if (cookie.getName().equals("cookieName")) {
     cookie.setValue("");
     cookie.setPath("/");
     cookie.setMaxAge(0);
     resp.addCookie(cookie);
  }
 }     
}
```